# Лямбда-выражение без ключевого слова it

Tags: kotlin

Я изучаю котлин. Возник простой вопрос. Как бы выглядело стандартное лямбда-выражение `numbers.sumOf { it * 2 }` без использования `it`? Я просто не понимаю, к чему относится `it`.

```
fun main() {
    val numbers = listOf(5, 42, 10, 4)
    println(numbers.sumOf { it * 2 }) // 122
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it` это элемент коллекции, передающийся в лямбда-функцию как параметр.

Без `it`:

```
println(numbers.sumOf { element -> element * 2 })
```